# Concurrency, triggers, schema legacy, foreign keys and performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, azure-sql-database

Imagine you developed a software that had an architecture that wanted a different database for each of your users. The schema of this database is full of tables with IDENTITY PKs, and other tables full of FK referencing these tables.

Now, at a certain point, you need to collapse all those databases into one big database. You, for sure, changed the PK of the tables, removing the IDENTITY constraint and changing the PK to ID + TenantID.

To solve the issue with the ID, you simulate the IDENTITY by creating a trigger. This trigger overwrites the INSERT statement (INSTEAD OF INSERT) and, transactionally, reads the last value used as ID from an "IdentityTable", use it to insert the record and updates the value incremented by 1 in the "IdentityTable".

Everything works perfectly, except for the concurrency. If there are two concurrent inserts, triggers are transactional, but not isolated. That means that only one of the N executed insert statements will succeed.

Now, I'm not a DBA, but if I'm not wrong, by using a SERIALIZABLE transaction level, I'd solve this issue. For sure my queries will be slower, but safer. So, as soon as I spin a trigger, I set the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE and I'm guaranteed that as soon as the trigger completes the isolation level is set back to the original value[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql#remarks).

Now. I know this solution stinks. In my opinion it stinks since I decided to go this way (when I had to collapse all the databases). But what should have done?
How should I have solved the colliding PK issues? How should I move from here? What would you do?

Comment: maybe using a guid as PK instead of an int would have helped here ?

Comment: Are you using a version of SQL Server that supports [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql)? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Comment: Yep. They are supported in Sql Azure (discovered today) since 2015. When I had to migrate (2011) they didn't exist. So, what do you suggest? Changing the trigger, modifying with the usage of Sequences?

Comment: FWIW: An `UPDATE` statement can do interesting things, e.g. `update IdentityTable set @NextValue = NextValue += 1 where TenantId = @TenantId`. That will both increment the value in the table and return the new value in `@NextValue`. (`set @Before = NextValue, NextValue += 1, @After = NextValue` returns both _before_ and _after_ values.)

Comment: That's true , that'd be a good implementation, at least to avoid locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To solve the issue with the ID, you simulate the IDENTITY by creating a trigger

That's a terrible idea.  There's no need to eliminate the IDENTITY column just because there's another column in the key.  Also you could have a SEQUENCE for each customer, if you really want.

eg

```
create table SomeTable
(
  CustomerID int,
  SomeTableID int identity,
  a int,
  b int,
  c int,
  constraint PK_SomeTable primary key (CustomerID,SomeTableID)
)
```

> Now, I'm not a DBA, but if I'm not wrong, by using a SERIALIZABLE transaction level, I'd solve this issue

You are wrong.  SERIALIZABLE won't help because it still allows concurrent reads.  You need to read the ID table in a transaction (the trigger ensures that), and use UPDLOCK in the SELECT.  This will apply a restrictive lock on the row before you read it, and ensure that no other session can read the row with UPDLOCK until the current session has updated it.

> What would you do?

Use IDENTITY or SEQUENCEs to generate the keys.

Comment: Ok, your voice makes me shake. But I swear that was not my idea! But, as someone used to say, ignorance makes you in a worst position. So let me explain... I had, let's say, 100 tables on 100 different databases, with the same name and same ID value inside. How could I keep the number going on per-tenant basis?

Comment: Why do you need the numbers to be per-tenant?  If you did, you could provision a separate SEQUENCE object for each tenant.

Comment: Because they are exposed outside. For example, one of this ID is the OrderID, and is per tenant basis. I must admit my ignorance: I don't know SEQUENCE. Where I can find more? Are they supported on Sql Azure?

Comment: Ok, for what I can read, sequences have been introducted in 2015 on SQL Azure. When we migrated to SQL Azure it was 2011... So that's problably the reason that who supported us didn't propose this solution. Let me further check on this topic.

Comment: David, I understand that the idea is terrible but it was decided a lot of years ago. In 2011 Sequences were not supported by SQL Azure. Now, can you summarize that was a terrible idea? What are the implications?

Comment: It may have been the best choice at the time, but generating your own IDs is error-prone and limits concurrency.  

If you were doing this from scratch, you wouldn't even consolidate the tenants into a single database.  You'd just have separate database in Elastic Pools.

Comment: Yes I get it. In which sense it "limits concurrency". In the sense that using locks (i.e. UPDLOCK) it slows down queries? Or are there other factors? About Elastic Pools, I went into them as soon as they were released but IMHO DTUs are very low for each tenant...

Answer (score 1):

So this really isn't a question that can be answered without a good deal of knowledge about the specific architecture of your application. I think the first mistake was to remove the identity property from all those columns. There was no need to do this. All you really needed to do was add tenant ID to the primary key (and then flow that change through the related tables). But assuming a good reason lies behind the identity removal (why?) I think a sequence would have been a better choice then this "max" approach?

So what would I do? Restore the identity columns and get rid of the trigger. From the database viewpoint, you're done. And since you now host multiple tenants in the same database, it might be a good idea to review security and permissions. And then address how you will provide the ability to restore a given tenant's information to a previous point in time. Usually when you make this type of change, there is a lot of work to be done in the client/reporting side. Did you try to skip that part?

Comment: Ok... The meaning was that those IDs were exposed outside, so I had to keep it during the migration. Because of this needs I had to "find" a solution (what really happened is that an 'important' guy gave me this solution) that allowed me to keep the IDs and let them grow on per-customer basis. I would love to get rid of the trigger... But how would I get this "identity" per tenant? Will sequences save me?